# Flutter Web FilePicker browser crash or close without error on UBUNTU

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, flutter-web

I want to use flutter file picker on web platform. when i call method "pickFiles" app close without error

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
);
print(result?.files.first.bytes);
if (result?.files.first != null) {
  print(result?.files.first.bytes);
} else {
  throw "Cancelled File Picker";
}
```

I think this is happening only on ubuntu.

and flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.13.0-44-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem !
Temporarly i decide to use another package

```
flutter_dropzone: ^3.0.5
```

He helps me to put some files in the app.

```
onTap: () async {
            bool fileUploaded = false;
            double pourcentageUploaded = 0;
            await showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => Dialog(
                      child: StatefulBuilder(
                        builder: (context, setstate) => AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                          color: fileUploaded
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          height: 200,
                          width: 500,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              DropzoneView(
                                onDrop: (value) async {
                                  fileUploaded = !fileUploaded;
                                  do {
                                    pourcentageUploaded += 0.0000000004;
                                    print(pourcentageUploaded);
                                    setstate(() {});
                                  } while (pourcentageUploaded < 1);

                                  pourcentageUploaded = 0.4;
                                  setstate(() {});
                                },
                              ),
                              Center(
                                child: Text(fileUploaded
                                    ? 'Telechargement...'
                                    : 'Veuillez glisser le document ici'),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.transparent),
                                  height: 50,
                                  width: 500,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                                      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                      color: Colors.yellow[100],
                                      height: 50,
                                      width: pourcentageUploaded * 500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
```